# How to Populate a List Box (combo box) from a Multi-Dimensional Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a student in JavaScript and we have an assignment due tonight.  I've been working, and re-working, the code for bit.

Essentially, I'm struggling with populating a List Box (combo box) from a Multi-Dimensional Array.

I have a multi-dimensional array created and it works (I sent my results to an alert box).

```
var concertArray = [
        ["Billy Joel", "99", "equal.png"],
        ["Bryan Adams", "89", "higher.png"],
        ["Brian Adams", "25", "lower.png"]

        ];
```

But, I have no idea how to populate this array to a select list box (combo box).

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over the array?

Comment: What, **exactly,** should the generated HTML be for this example? Have you tried using a `for` loop?

Comment: to add the columns of Billy Joel, Bryan Adams, and Brian Adams to appear in the select box.

I then want to use the value to show price and the image to appear.

I think I can do the other things once I can populate the combo box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Code.

```
<html>

    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var concertArray = [
            ["Billy Joel", "99", "equal.png"],
            ["Bryan Adams", "89", "higher.png"],
            ["Brian Adams", "25", "lower.png"]
            ];

            function populate(){

                for(i=0;i<concertArray.length;i++){
                    var select = document.getElementById("test");
                    select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(concertArray[i][0], concertArray[i][1]);
                }

            }
        </script>
        </head>

    <body onload="populate();">
        <select id="test">
        </select>
    </body>     
</html>
```

this will help you.....

Comment: I don't mean to bother you any more than I have to.  I want to understand this.  So, if I wanted to pull the price [1] = 99 when Billy Joel [0] is selected, do you know how that would work?  It is okay if you don't, I'm just hoping to get a handle of this stuff as I can see how it can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

extract the data which you want to add in combo box from the array, then use `jquery append` to add them to the select tag.

```
<select id="test">
</select>
```

Iterate through the array & store the data to be added in a variable, say var data, then:

```
$('#test').append('<option value="'+data+'">'+data+'</option');
```

Comment: this is the main logic, iterate over the array & use this code yourself. No more help from my side. ;)

Comment: So, if I want to add the columns of Billy Joel, Bryan Adams, and Brian Adams to appear in the select box, how would I write that?

Comment: So, I need 

var data
  for (var i = 0; i < concertArray.length; i++) {
  $('#test').append('<option value="'+ data +'">'+ data +'</option');
  
  }