# I want to load uppercase letter into combobox

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, uppercase

javascript part: 
Html part is quite ok. But I get output from alert message but can not load data into [combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267982/how-to-populate-a-list-box-combo-box-from-a-multi-dimensional-array)..

```
 function count_array()
        {
            var str = document.getElementById("InputText").value;

            for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++)
            {

                if (str[i] == str[i].toUpperCase())
                {
                    letter = str[i];

                    alert("Array:" + "{" + letter  + " -"  + str.indexOf(str[i]) + "}");
          }


       }


   }
```

Comment: why you can't? explain please

Comment: Just FYI: if you want to remove all non-uppercase ASCII letters from a string, you may use `str.replace(/[^A-Z]+/g,'')`. Can you please show a fiddle to have a better understanding of what you are doing?